# Update a column with the combined results of multiple other columns in the same table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to combine the results of a SELECT into a single column within the same table (moving from individual columns to storing multiple fields in a JSON object).  My SELECT query works fine, but when I try to combine it with an UPDATE I get:

> You can't specify target table 'app_config' for update in FROM clause

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong (and I'm not that great at SQL), so any help would be appreciated.

Combined SQL:

```
UPDATE app_config
SET sms_config = ( 
    SELECT CONCAT( '{"user_name":"', app_id, '","user_id":', sms_user_id, ',"user_auth":"', sms_user_auth, '"}' ) 
    FROM app_config
    WHERE sms_user_id IS NOT NULL AND sms_user_id > 0 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
UPDATE app_config
SET sms_config = CONCAT( '{"user_name":"', app_id, '","user_id":'
                      , sms_user_id,  ',"user_auth":"', sms_user_auth, '"}')
WHERE sms_user_id > 0
```

Comment: That's giving me 0 rows affected.  My previous SELECT query alone (without the UPDATE) returns 15 rows.  Shouldn't there be a SELECT somewhere?

Comment: You don't need a SELECT when UPDATING. You are saying this returns 15: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM app_config WHERE sms_user_id IS NOT NULL AND sms_user_id > 0`?

Comment: Correct.  15 on your SELECT.

Comment: I am at a loss: This clause `sms_user_id IS NOT NULL` should be irrelevant when `sms_user_id > 0` - by definition sms_user_id has to be non-null for the greater than operator to return true. I changed the solution to your WHERE clause.

Comment: Ya, I think you're correct on not needing the IS NOT NULL, but even with it I still get 0 rows affected.  If I just run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM app_config WHERE sms_user_id > 0` I also get 15.

Comment: I am 99% confident that is the correct answer. Can you check if the sms_config field has the values? Is there any way a trigger is on app_config and rolling back the update? There is also a 1% chance I have completely lost my mind and am missing a basic concept.

Comment: So ya, I probably should have checked sms_config instead of blindly paying attention to the rows affected message.  It has definitely been updated.  I'm going to restore this DB from a backup and run it again, but it looks like it's working.  I'll mark this answer as correct once I've verified.  Thanks, and sorry for causing you to question your sanity :)

Comment: Marked correct and rolled back to your original, as the IS NOT NULL was unnecessary.